# What is the difference between a functor that commutes with limits and a functor that preserves limits?

Tags: category-theory

Let $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ be a functor between two categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ where the notion of $F$ preserving and commuting limits makes sense. I am unable to understand the difference between those two things. So my question is as follows:

> What is the difference between a functor that commutes with limits and a functor that preserves limits?

Comment: There is no difference. Both notions always make sense and are the same notion.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Oh, OK. Thanks! What about in the quasicategory case? Like what is the difference between "preserve small limits" and "commutes with finite limits"?

Comment: There is still no difference between "preserves" and "commutes with," but small limits are more general than finite limits.

Comment: $\omega$ is an ordinal, not a Grothendieck universe. Presumably you mean something like the Grothendieck universe of hereditarily finite sets, in which case yes, but nobody ever works in that Grothendieck universe. Nearly everyone is happy to assume that $\mathbb{N}$ is a set and hence that "small limits" includes $\mathbb{N}$-indexed limits, at the very least.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Why don't you write an answer to this question?

Comment: Because I wanted to make sure the OP was asking the question they intended to ask.

Comment: Some people like to say "commutes", some people like to say "preserves". It's like saying a group homomorphism _commutes_ with the group operation vs a group homomorphism _preserves_ the group operation.

Answer (score 5):

In the comments it was claimed that the notions are equivalent. But I claim that there is a subtle difference in the *language*.

If $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ is a functor, then we say that $F$ preserves limits if for every limit cone $(L \to X_i)$ in $\mathcal{C}$ its image $(F(L) \to F(X_i))$ is also a limit cone in $\mathcal{D}$. Notice that this definition makes sense even if $\mathcal{C}$ has not all limits, and it is not assumed *a priori* that the diagram $(F(X_i))$ in $\mathcal{D}$ has *some* limit. But this would be necessary to speak of "commutation". Specifically, if $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ is a functor, $\mathcal{C}$ has limits of shape $I$ and $\mathcal{D}$ too, then the phrase "$F$ commutes with limits of shape $I$" should mean that the canonical morphism
$$F(\lim_i X_i) \to \lim_i F(X_i)$$
is an isomorphism for every $I$-shaped diagram $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$. For $F$ to commute with some operation, we need the existence of such operation.